# Disable tabs in child grid doesn't work correctly ( Kendo-UI )

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-tabstrip

When I use this code to disable 2nd and 3rd tab in each detailed row (child grid) I see that only the first expanded row and the rows before it have tabs disabled - and all other rows below have enabled tabs - what am I doing wrong?

Tried to put this code both inside and outside **function detailInit(e) {}**

```
var tabStrip = $("#mytabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
        tabStrip.disable(tabStrip.tabGroup.children().eq(1));
        tabStrip.disable(tabStrip.tabGroup.children().eq(2));


<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
     <div class="tabstrip" id="mytabstrip">
         <button id="gridButton">gridButton</button>
         <ul>
             <li class="k-state-active" id="AccountsTab">
                 Счета                       
             </li>
             <li id="AccountInfoTab">
                 Полная информация по счету:
             </li>
             <li id="BillEventsTab">
                 Просмотр событий по счету:
             </li>
         </ul>
         <div>
             <div id="account" class="Account"></div>
         </div>

     </div>

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that make an impression in the provided code:

- The TabStrip ID is the same for all detail templates. Duplicate IDs are not allwed by web standards and lead to inability to obtain reference to the respective elements, except the first one. Do not use IDs in the detail template at all, or make them inique by using (concatenating) the ID of the master data item. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate
- Make sure the TabStrip for each detail template is initialized only once. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/jquery-initialization#duplicate-initialization

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dimodi it's a useful info, I've checked my code and changed refers to class instead of ID's, checked that no duplicate initialization occur - but it didn't help. Than I spotted that in the example they use **detailRow.find**. Now when using "detailRow.find" each row will have identical behavior. Thanks again and have a nice day!!!

```
function detailInit(e) {

        var detailRow = e.detailRow;

        detailRow.find(".tabstrip")
            .kendoTabStrip({
                animation: {
                    open: { effects: "fadeIn" }
                },


            });



        tabStrip = detailRow.find(".tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");

        tabStrip.disable(tabStrip.tabGroup.children().eq(1));
        tabStrip.disable(tabStrip.tabGroup.children().eq(2));
```